# How to Create Application Id in paypal?

Tags: android, paypal

i want to integrate #MPL(Mobile Payment Library)# on my android application.

but i don't no how to create Application id.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use the old MPL - which is now deprecated - you can create an application id from http://apps.paypal.com/.

I would recommend using the new PayPal iOS and Android libraries from https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/